# Where have I gone wrong with my React App installation?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking to get started with learning React. I followed the installation steps on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm in order to set up the environment. When I reach the final stage where I enter the command `npm start` into the cmd prompt, the development server starts and it compiles successfully but the http://localhost:3000/ doesn't display the expect React logo on the screen although the React logo is displayed in the tab. Does anyone know where I may have gone wrong? The browser I am using is Google Chrome, if that's of any assistance.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in console?

Comment: @h-des I've been editing the files in notepad++ (only for installation) so there's no console I can refer to. However I intended to install visual studio afterwards

Comment: There is a console in your browser :) you can use F12 on most system to see it. That's very important tool for FE developers so you should porobably start using it

Comment: Also if you are new to react I highly recommend https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app instead of a manual webpack + babel setup

Comment: Apologies for that, I've checked the browser console and it says Waiting for update signal from WDS...  & react-dom.development.js:27773  **Download the React DevTools for a better development experience:** with a link to react devtools

Comment: I removed the `cmd` tag as it is not related, the fact that it is used to launch a command using `cmd` does not make the issue related to `cmd`.

Comment: Agree with the using of `create-react-app`. It's as simple as creating a new app, cd'ing into the directory and running `npm start`. Much more straight forward, especially if you're just learning react, start with the basic tools provided.

Comment: Thanks so much, the `create-react-app` suggestion was very helpful